# Mouse down on specific positions of an element in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I would like to move my mouse pointer to a specific position over a canvas relative to its `top left (0, 0) coordinates`, hold my mouse down, move it to another position on the canvas and release (similar to drag and drop but on a single canvas/same element).

I cant figure out how to do this. I have tried using `.performActions()` as so:

```
browser.performActions([{
  ....
  actions: [
    { type: 'pointerMove', origin: canvas, x: canvasOffset.x, y: canvasOffset.y },
    { type: 'pointerDown', button: 0 },
    { type: 'pointerMove', origin: 'pointer', targetOffset.x, targetOffset.y },
    { type: 'pointerUp', button: 0 }
}])
```

but it seems that using this moves the mouse pointer relative to the center of the canvas instead of its top left corner, so the `pointerDown` action happens at `canvas' center + offsets`, instead of canvas `top left + offsets`

I am on version 6 of webdriverIO so that means using:

```
 browser.moveToElement('#canvas-selector', canvasOffset.x, canvasOffset.y)
```

or

```
canvas.moveTo({xOffset: x, yOffset: y})
```

doesn't work either as it seems these methods are no longer provided in wdio's api.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.